# Django - Referential integrity on OneToOneField

Tags: django, django-models, one-to-one

I am trying to import a product feed (`Product`) into Django. I need to maintain a set of selected products (`SelectedProduct`) which also hold overrides for the product descriptions. I thought the best way to represent this is as a `OneToOneField` linking `SelectedProduct` with `Product`.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=32, primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)

class SelectedProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.OneToOneField(Product, db_column='product_sku', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
```

For simplicity, each time the product feed is read, I am intending to delete all the products and re-import the whole product feed (within a transaction, so I can rollback if required).

However, I don't want to truncate the `SelectedProduct` at the same time, since this contains the descriptions which have been overridden. I was hoping that `models.DO_NOTHING` might help, but it doesn't.

I suppose I either need to temporarily disable the referential integrity while I import the feed (and delete any entries from `SelectedProduct` which would break the integrity) or I need to represent the relationship differently.

Any advice appreciated please :-)

Note - the above is a simplified representation. I have variants hanging off products too and will have selected variants overriding variant prices.

Comment: Is there a reason why delete + re-import is simpler than, say, using update_or_create?  Do items disappear from the feed over time?

Comment: @TimNyborg Yes exactly, products will be regularly removed from the feed so I need to account for this somehow. I will have a look at update_or_create though, perhaps there is a better way to manage this when importing the data.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I went with the suggestion from @TimNyborg to use `update_or_create`. The data load now takes roughly 10 times as long, but as it's a batch import of a small-ish dataset the performance isn't an issue and it feels like a better solution overall.